# Fusioncharts/3.3.1-sr3.21100 print preview not showing up in chrome 41

Tags: fusioncharts

My application is using Fusioncharts/3.3.1-sr3.21100.

When ctrl+p is done, the graphs don't show in print preview of either latest chrome 41 or the latest firefox 36

Works fine on IE 11.

Please let me know your thoughts..

Thanks,
Manish

Answer (score 0):

As much as I can say about your issue, the issue can just be with the version of FusionCharts(if any). The best option would be to get the latest version of [Fusioncharts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/version-history/), which I can see is available in their website.